# Get unique values of a column in Pandas and group the values of other columns by them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have the following dataframe in Pandas:

| Name | Sport | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Soccer | 20 |
| Ronald | Basketball | 31 |
| Mary | Rugby | 20 |
| Ronald | Tennis | 31 |
| Ronald | Golf | 31 |
| Jennifer | Tennis | 18 |
| Jennifer | Soccer | 18 |

And just like I could do in SQL, I need to isolate the unique names the unique sports. However, each unique sport must become a column, so I can display how many times it appeared, like this:

| Name | Soccer | Basketball | Rugby | Tennis | Golf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Ronald | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Jennifer | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I'm completely lost and don't know how to solve that. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: this is just a pivot/crosstab `pd.crosstab(df['Name'],df['Sport'])` ? Unless i'm missing something

Comment: Jesus man, thank you so, so much. I spent more than 3 hours trying to solve this problem and you gave me an answer only a few minutes after I posted! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!